# add a "flag" column about whether one ID has certain values in one other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

The dataframe is like:

```
 In [1]: df
 Out[2]:
          userid type
    0      1       1
    1      1       2
    2      2       1
    3      3       1
    4      3       2
    5      3       3
```

Now I want to add a column to it about whether the userid has certain values in "type" columns(let's say type1 and type2).
This is what I desire in output:

```
 In [1]: df
 Out[2]:
          userid type  has_type_12
    0      1       1      1
    1      1       2      1
    2      2       1      0
    3      3       1      1
    4      3       2      1
    5      3       3      1
```

Is there a quick solution for this?

---

I have left out one situation, where userID 3  may has more types like 3 or 4.In this case, I would like to tag has_type_12 = 1 for 3. I have modified the input and the desired output above.

Comment: have more  categories  like 3 or 4.  I have modified the test set above.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [308]: df['has_type_12'] = \
              df.groupby('userid')['type'].transform(lambda x: x[x.isin([1,2])].nunique() == 2)

In [309]: df
Out[309]:
   userid  type  has_type_12
0       1     1            1
1       1     2            1
2       2     1            0
3       3     1            1
4       3     2            1
5       3     3            1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `set`s:

```
cats = [1,2]
df['has_type_12'] = df.groupby('userid')['type'] \
                      .transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set((cats))) \
                      .astype(int) 
print (df)
   userid  type  has_type_12
0       1     1            1
1       1     2            1
2       2     1            0
3       3     1            1
4       3     2            1
5       3     3            1
```

Another solution with double [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) (if only a few categories):

```
cats = [1,2]
df['has_type_12'] = df.groupby('userid')['type'] \
                      .transform(lambda x: ((x == 1).any()) & ((x == 2).any())) \
                      .astype(int) 
print (df)
   userid  type  has_type_12
0       1     1            1
1       1     2            1
2       2     1            0
3       3     1            1
4       3     2            1
5       3     3            1
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `set`s the `>=` operator tests whether the right hand side is a subset of the left hand side.  I use the `ge` method as a proxy for `>=`

**Using `groupby`**

```
m = df.groupby('userid').type.apply(set)
df.assign(
  has_type_12=df.userid.map(m).ge({1, 2}).astype(int)
)

   userid  type  has_type_12
0       1     1            1
1       1     2            1
2       2     1            0
3       3     1            1
4       3     2            1
5       3     3            1
```

**Using `defaultdict`**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
[d[k].add(v) for k, v in zip(df.userid.values.tolist(), df.type.values.tolist())];
df.assign(has_type_12=df.userid.map(d).ge({1, 2}).astype(int))

   userid  type  has_type_12
0       1     1            1
1       1     2            1
2       2     1            0
3       3     1            1
4       3     2            1
5       3     3            1
```

---

**Timing**
*large data*

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        userid=np.random.randint(1000, size=100000),
        type=np.random.randint(100, size=100000)
    ))

%%timeit
d = defaultdict(set)
[d[k].add(v) for k, v in zip(df.userid.values.tolist(), df.type.values.tolist())];
df.userid.map(d).ge({1, 2}).astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 55.6 ms per loop

%%timeit 
m = df.groupby('userid').type.apply(set)
df.userid.map(m).ge({1, 2}).astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 76.1 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby('userid')['type'] \
                      .transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set((cats))) \
                      .astype(int)
1 loop, best of 3: 206 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby and take unique type ids for each use then check if it contains {1,2}.

```
df['has_type_12'] = df.groupby('userid')['type']\
  .apply(lambda x: set(x).issuperset({1,2}))\
  .astype(int).values[df.userid]
```